# Errors trying to read from a .dat file

Tags: java, read-write

I am having an error reading a from a .dat file. The .dat file is set up like this:

```
<Name>/<age>
```

and I use the / as a delimiter.
I am attempting to read from the file to read the name and age, but it comes up with this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
        at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:819)
        at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1431)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2040)
        at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2000)
        at Lab04a.input(Lab04a.java:26)
        at Lab04a.main(Lab04a.java:18)
Java Result: 1
```

The problematic method is this:

```
public void input() {
        try {
            File dat = new File("Lab04a.dat");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(dat).useDelimiter("/");
            String name = sc.next();
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            Lab.process(name, age);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Missing or corrupted data file.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

The lines giving errors are lines 26 and 18, and these are the lines:

Line 18:

```
Lab.input();
```

And line 26:

```
int age = sc.nextInt();
```

Line 18 can't have anything wrong, as it only calls the problematic method.
Line 26 is (to my best guess) where the error is occurring.

Comment: Can you please post up your file content as well? thank you :)

Comment: The `Scanner` is looking for an integer after the `/` and the file does not contain any integer.

Comment: @manouti when the file content is not clear how we can be sure about it?

Comment: @manouti what is gonna happen if you have ssss/11111 ?

Comment: @KickButtowski Nevermind. I just based my comment on the content he provided: `<Name>/<age>`

Comment: @Nick D. please provide your file content ?

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
int age = sc.nextInt();
```

can give you InputMismatchException if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range

Comment: what is gonna happen if you have ssss/11111 ?

Comment: Call to sc.next() will print ssss and sc.nextInt() will print 11111 .

Comment: so how do you know your answer will help the op when you donot know about the file content?

Comment: Because of the fact that there are 2 lines in method input() where scanner is used , next() cannot throw InputMismatchException but nextInt can.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(dat).useDelimiter("\\/");
```

**EDIT**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.*;

/**
 * @author Davide
 */
public class test {
    static Map map;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // init value
        input();
    }


    public static void input() {
        try {
            File dat = new File("test.dat");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(dat).useDelimiter("\\/");
            String name = sc.next();
            int age = sc.nextInt();
            System.out.println(name + " " + age);
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Missing or corrupted data file.");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

}
```

**dat file**

```
ciao/56
```

**UPDATE**

```
try {
    // ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    sc.next(); 
}
```

Comment: this code does not help the op. you do not know the file content. giving the code answer is not right